# Shiv'a Ushloshim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred thirty-seven?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Rashi, 237 years elapsed between two times when there was a prominent leader of the Jewish People (or a major segment thereof) descended from Yissachar.

The details:

One of the shofetim (whose career is described in Judg. 10:1-2) was Tola, of the tribe of Yissachar, who served for twenty-three years. Rashi's explanation of the "300 years" mentioned ibid. 11:26 puts Tola's judgeship in the years 238-261 since the entry into Eretz Yisrael, or 2726-2749 since Creation. (Other commentaries reconstruct the chronology differently.)

The third king of the Ten Tribes, Baasha, was also from the tribe of Yissachar (I Kings 15:27). He began to reign in the year 2986 since Creation. ([Seder Hadoros](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46817&pgnum=133))

2986 - 2749 = 237.

Comment: Psssch... very impressive research!  +1

Answer (score 1):

In gematria (is that allowed for these questions?), 237 equals:
`אלה הם מועדי יהוה` (These are the festivals of the Lord)
From Vayikra, leading up to the commandments of Shavuot and Omer (apropo for today...)

Comment: Hey @AviD, fancy meeting you here, too!  :)  +1 for a very cool answer!

Comment: Actually, though, there's no such verse. Lev. 23:2 says אלה הם מועדי (without Hashem's name), and vv. 4 and 37 say 'אלה מועדי ה (without הם).

Comment: Gematria is certainly allowed. Up in these high numbers, it's sometimes the best we can do!

Comment: @Alex is correct, that verse is *close*, but not quite. Still, I'll leave it for entertainment value...